# Sum elements in a matrix

Tags: java, matrix

I´m trying to sum all the elements of a single row in a matrix, I´m pretty sure this outputs an error message (Index out of range) since I´ve always made this mistake before in Python. I want to sum the elements in a loop too pls!
(This matrix has a single column and a X ammount of rows. Sorry I didn´t clarify)

```
public class cls_ejercicio7_d {
    private int tamaño;
    private String[] lista_nombres;
    private double[][] lista_kilometraje;

    public cls_ejercicio7_d(int tamaño, String lista_nombres[], double lista_kilometraje[][]) {
        this.lista_kilometraje = lista_kilometraje;
        this.lista_nombres = lista_nombres;
        this.tamaño = tamaño;
    }

    public double[][] resultados(int tamaño, String lista_nombres[], double lista_kilometraje[][]) {
        double total;
        double[][] lista_totales = new double[tamaño][1];
        for (int i = 0; i < tamaño; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tamaño; j++) {
                total = lista_kilometraje[i][j] + lista_kilometraje[i][j + 1];
                lista_totales[i][j] = total;
            }
        }
        return lista_totales;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
 double [][]lista_totales=new double[tamaño][1];
```

do

```
 double [][]lista_totales=new double[tamaño][tamaño];
```

and

```
 for (int j = 0; j < tamaño; j++) {
                total+=lista_kilometraje[i][j];
            }
            lista_totales[i][1]=total;
```

Comment: This matrix has a single column and a X ammount of rows. Sorry I didn´t clarify.

Comment: Thanks I totally forgot about it haha I derped

Answer (score 1):

Error is from this line :

total=lista_kilometraje[i][j]+lista_kilometraje[i][j+1];

You are taking `j+1`. Assuming your matrix has 8 columns  so for this one it will try to retrieve `j[8]` which is wrong as J only have index 7.

Also the size of `lista_totales = [tamaño][1]`

`lista_totales[i][j]` will also throw exception.

u may want to change to below :

```
public double [][] resultados(int tamaño,String lista_nombres[],double lista_kilometraje[][]){
    double total;
    double [][]lista_totales=new double[tamaño][1];
    for (int i = 0; i < tamaño; i++) {
        total = 0 ; 
        for (int j = 0; j < tamaño; j++) {
            total+=lista_kilometraje[i][j];
        }
        lista_totales[i][1]=total;
    }
    return lista_totales;
}
```

Comment: Yes! @nimi0112,got it too, I totally forgot about it haha Thank you so much

Comment: U need to reset `total=0` every time for first loop else :)

Answer (score 1):

Following line is having problem

```
total = lista_kilometraje[i][j] + lista_kilometraje[i][j + 1];
```

in this your j loop is iterating to j < n and for last iteration you are trying to access j+1 so that index does not exist.

either you can try in for loop

```
j < tamaño-1
```